# Spring 4 + Hibernate 4 + POSTGRES + TOMCAT 6 JNDI error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, tomcat

I have a problem in a deploy on tomcat 6 but i can't find the error.

> nov 14, 2014 3:01:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet spring threw exception
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at

This is my configuration

context.xml in tomcat 6

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
   maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"
   name="jdbc/applicationTestJNDI"      password="ssss"
   type="javax.sql.DataSource"
   url="jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/applicationTestJNDI"
   username="sssss" />
```

------ application context

```
    <bean id="dataSourceOne" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/applicationTestJNDI"/>
        <property name="cache" value="false"/>
        <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactoryOne" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceOne" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>             
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                 <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            </props>
       </property>
       <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>user.hbm.xml</value>

            </list>
        </property>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="TransactionManagerConcentrador" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryOne"/>
        <qualifier value="exampleone"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Gestor de transsacciones -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="TransactionManagerConcentrador" />
```

--- web xml----

```
    <resource-ref>
        <description>applicationTestJNDI</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/applicationTestJNDI</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    </resource-ref>
```

Comment: Please provide stacktrace.

Comment: Completed! Is normal that the in the stactrace appears sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver?